# Why aren't my PivotFilters working and why does my macro only work on my computer?

Tags: excel, templates, filter, pivot-table, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and writing a macro in VBA. I have 2 problems: 1-Most of my PivotFilters don't actually filter, and 2-I've made this macro for an Excel macro-enabled template which works fine on my machine, but if email the template and try to run the macro on another machine I get the error: method createpivottable of object pivotcache failed.

```
Sub RunResourceReport()

' Create the Resource Requests Pivot Table
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CP Monthly Data").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CP Monthly Data!R1C1:R486C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="Resource Requests", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Resource Requests"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests")
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .AllowMultipleFilters = True
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium4"
End With

' Turn off subtotals.
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Probability Status"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Project"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Project manager"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Company name"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields( _
    "Workgroup Name").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields( _
    "Workgroup Name").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionBeginsWith, Value1:="Custom"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Workgroup Name")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Company name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields( _
    "Probability Status").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="X"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields( _
    "Probability Status")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Project")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Project manager" _
    )
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 4
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Resource name"). _
    PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionBeginsWith, Value1:="*TBD"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Resource name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 5
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 0, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 1, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 2, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 3, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 3, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 4, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 4, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 5, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 5, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").AddDataField ActiveSheet. _
    PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 6, _
    Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Probability Status"). _
    AutoSort xlDescending, "Probability Status"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Resource name"). _
    AutoSort xlAscending, "Resource name"
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

' Create the Resource Monthly Detail Pivot Table
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CP Monthly Data").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CP Monthly Data!R1C1:R486C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="Resource Monthly Detail" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Resource Monthly Detail"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail")
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .AllowMultipleFilters = True
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
End With

' Turn off subtotals.
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Workgroup Name"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Project"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Project manager"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Resource name"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Resource name").ShowDetail = _
    False

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Probability Status")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    .PivotItems("X - Lost - 0%").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("X - On Hold - 0%").Visible = False
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields( _
    "Workgroup Name").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionBeginsWith, Value1:="Custom"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Workgroup Name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Resource name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Project")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 3, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 3, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 4, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 4, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 5, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 5, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Workgroup Name").AutoSort _
    xlAscending, "Workgroup Name"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Monthly Detail").PivotFields("Resource name").AutoSort _
    xlAscending, "Resource name"
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

' Create the Resource Monthly Detail By Project Pivot Table
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CP Monthly Data").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CP Monthly Data!R1C1:R486C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
    CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="", TableName:="RMD By Project" _
    , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Resource Detail By Project"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project")
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .AllowMultipleFilters = True
    .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium6"
End With

' Turn off subtotals.
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Workgroup Name"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Project"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Probability Status"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Resource name"). _
    Subtotals(1) = False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Project").ShowDetail = _
    False

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields( _
    "Workgroup Name").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionBeginsWith, Value1:="Custom"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Workgroup Name")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields( _
    "Probability Status").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionDoesNotContain, Value1:="X"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Probability Status" _
    )
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Probability Status"). _
    AutoSort xlDescending, "Probability Status"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Project")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").PivotFields("Resource name")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 0, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 2, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 3, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 3, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 4, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 4, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 5, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 5, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("RMD By Project").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "RMD By Project").PivotFields(Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now()), "mmmm, yyyy")), _
    Format(DateAdd("m", 6, Now()), "mmm"), xlSum
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Executive Summary").Select
Range("A1:M66").Value = Range("A1:M66").Value

End Sub
```

The PivotFilter used on the Probability Status field works just fine, but I need to only show the items that begin with "Custom" for Workgroup Name.

I've tried changing Visible to false using:

```
For Each PivItem In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Resource Requests").PivotFields("Workgroup Name").PivotItems
    Select Case PivItem.Name
    Case "Custom*"
        PivItem.Visible = True
    Case Else
        PivItem.Visible = False
    End Select
Next PivItem
```

but then get the error "unable to set the visible property of the pivotitem class" when it hits the line to change Visible to False.

Please help on either or both of my problems!

Answer (score 0):

The answer probably lies in the excel version that your client is using. Try changing this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CP Monthly Data!R1C1:R486C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="Resource Requests", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

To this, in their copy of the program:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "CP Monthly Data!R1C1:R486C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="Resource Requests", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion12
```